# Sort a Single linked-list using bubble sort

Tags: java, linked-list

The link to the problem set is : https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-list/

While implementing the code for sorting a linked list using bubble sort I am facing this error:

Cannot read field "next" because "" is null (at line 15)

The code for the above error is :

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode sortList(ListNode head) {
        ListNode io;
        ListNode jo;
        for (io = head; io.next.next != null; io = io.next) {
            for (jo = io.next; jo.next != null; jo = jo.next) {
                if (io.val > jo.val) {
                    int temp = io.val;
                    io.val = jo.val;
                    jo.val = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```